# Should i call onCreate method in onDestroy method in android service?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I want to startservice again when it was destroyed.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        onCreate();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit - why you would want to restart the service in `onDestroy()`. I mean why don't you just make it a long running instead of destroying and revoking it. Or is it because the Android system kills it? If you tell us more about the conditions you are facing we can provide a better answer fitting to your actual problem.

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy i want to create a socketserver in my application. and other device will communicate with this server. But last night server stop automatically so i want to restart server when it stop.

Comment: Did you try running it as a foreground service already and with START_STICKY?

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy it is background service and i have written belowe code,
`@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }`

Comment: @Jenish Since Android Oreo there are some [limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) on running background services. So if your service needs to be alive it must be a foreground service. The provided link also have a section `Migration Guide` which helps you to migrate to foreground service.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this . This is not going to do anything. To restart a service you should restart it on **onTaskRemove()** like below.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);
}
```