# Broadcast Receiver not calling Service while app was killed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

My target was **Restarting the Service** when app is in background or even killed from home page by sweeping. App & Service is working nice while app is in foreground and background but while I killed the app by force(sweeping out from home page), the **Service** stopped working. That's okay but I implemented a **Broadcast Receiver** to restart the **Service** but it seems like **its (Broadcast Receiver)** not even called **itself** or the **Service** while app was killed forcefully / sweeping from home page.

My device is : **Xiaomi Redmi Note 4**

I included my codes here :

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.turzo.servicetest;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = "ServiceTest";
    Intent mServiceIntent;
    private SensorService mSensorService;

    Context ctx;

    public Context getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;
        registerRec();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorService = new SensorService(getCtx());
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(getCtx(), mSensorService.getClass());
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(mSensorService.getClass())) {
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        }

    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i (TAG, true+"");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i (TAG, false+"");
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       stopService(mServiceIntent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy!");
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    public void registerRec(){


        SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver myreceiver = new SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver((BroadcastReceiver) myreceiver, intentFilter);
    }







}
```

**SensorService.java**

```
package com.turzo.servicetest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class SensorService extends Service {
    public int counter=0;
    private String TAG = "ServiceTest";
    public SensorService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        Log.i(TAG , "here I am!");
    }

    public SensorService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startTimer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG , "ondestroy!");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.turzo.servicetest.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        stoptimertask();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    long oldTime=0;
    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
    }

    /**
     * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
     */
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG , "in timer ++++  "+ (counter++));
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * not needed
     */
    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

**SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package com.turzo.servicetest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stops! Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");

        context.startService(new Intent(context, SensorService.class));
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.turzo.servicetest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name="com.turzo.servicetest.SensorService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.turzo.servicetest.SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.turzo.servicetest.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Be specific . Did your broadcast get called or not ? Apart from that starting from android O you can not use `startService` from background so thats makes it useless . You probably look for some other way around .

Comment: No, Broadcast Receiver not called.

Comment: Try to use `sendBroadcast()` in `onTaskRemoved()` of `Service`. Or Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/47587789/4168607.

Comment: @ADM, that solved the problem like a charm! :D
Answer it and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart `Service` in `onTaskRemoved()`.

```
  @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);
    }
```

**NOTE:-** Starting from android O . You can not call `startService`.

> The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

This does not apply to foreground services, which are noticeable to the user. It can run in background with a notification on top. By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that target Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher. However, users can enable most of these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if the app targets an API level lower than 26. So in case if user enables the restrictions for below API 26 your `Service` will not work. 
Read [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

So Try to avoid using `Service` if you can . Make use of  [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) if it fits the requirements.

Comment: So if I use this type of Service, the app will run perfectly in the devices those are running OS lower than Oreo? And app will crash or throws an IllegalStateException in the devices those are running Oreo or higher OS ?
My target SDK is 26

Comment: Yeah Hopefully. See Doze and app standby modes introduces in Android M . So if you are doing network operations in your `Service`  then this can also affect your work. Read about  Background Execution Limits, DOZE, App standBy , Cached Process .

Comment: @ADM does it work for OS 9 or 10? because in my case sometimes broadcast receiver not gets called.

Comment: @DebasishMondal Unfortunately it will not work . Because there are now so much limitation over the years .. Pls read about [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) and other latest stuff about Broadcast ..

Comment: @ADM Thanks for your replay, but can you tell me is there any way to create an alarm which can work like default one.

Comment: Alarm manager will work with exact. I do not know your usecase so i can not tell more . probably you can post a seperate question with problem and code snippet .

Comment: @ADM Thanks, I will do that, but I just wanted to know that is there any way to call Broadcast Receiver even if the app is killed from the background because sometimes it gets called and sometimes not. I cannot find the exact scenario. Can you please help with that.