# Using alarmmanager, Service is not being restarted after application being killed?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have made a simple example where a toast message will be shown after a time gap. I am using alarmmanager for scheduling a service from where the toast message will be shown. Now the problem is when the app is running it works properly, but when I close the app from task-manager the service is not getting restarted. Below is my service code

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Alarm Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

}

and below is my alarmmanager code :

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10, pendingIntent);
```

Now, what is the solution for this? I need to keep the alarm even I close the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually implement `BroadcastReceiver` at `onDestroy` to restart the service once the app/service is close by the system/user.

You can check the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412264/broadcast-receiver-not-calling-service-while-app-was-killed), and a tutorial for you, check [here](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android).

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried this. But not working. Service is not getting restarted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below :-

> return Service.START_CONTINUATION_MASK;