# Service Ended When I Kill App

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

I have Developed App for detect outgoing and Incoming Call. I wrote Service For Background Call detection. It worked well for API 23 but it works for more than that it wasn't. Assist me to clear this Bug Please

Manifest File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="in.ds.buttdail.buttdial">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:isolatedProcess="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DialActivity" />

    <service
        android:name=".ButtDial.CallDetectService"

        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Utils.IncomingCallActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
    <activity android:name=".Utils.OutGoingCallActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".ButtDial.PhoneCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped"></receiver>

    <activity android:name=".ButtDial.CallEndActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

CallDetect Service

```
public class CallDetectService extends Service {
private CallHelper callHelper;

public CallDetectService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    callHelper = new CallHelper(this);

    int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    callHelper.start();
    return res;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("IWillStartAuto"));
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    callHelper.stop();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // not supporting binding
    return null;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public CallDetectService getService() {
        return CallDetectService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    //  sendBroadcast(new Intent("IWillStartAuto"));
}
}
```

Call Helper

I have Coded this to detect incoming and outgoing call.but it doesnt detect when i kill my application

```
public class CallHelper {
private final int interval = 5000; // 1 Second
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable;
private String checkedcall,userChecked;
/**
 * Listener to detect incoming calls.
 */
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        System.out.println("**********Call State is: " + state + "*********");
        Var.share = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Var.PERF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String incomings = Var.share.getString(Var.INCOMING, "");
        Log.e("incomings", incomings);
        if (incomings.equals("incoming")) {
            switch (state) {

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                    System.out.println("**********Inside CAll_STATE_RINGING state - case*********");

                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                    String tempData = date + "::" + "Incoming::" + incomingNumber + "\n";

                    //  Toast.makeText(ctx, date + ": " + "Incoming: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent incoming = new Intent(ctx, IncomingCallActivity.class);
                    incoming.putExtra("mobilenumber", incomingNumber);
                    incoming.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    ctx.startActivity(incoming);
                    break;
                case 0:

                    try {

                        Var.share = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Var.PERF, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String Call = Var.share.getString(Var.CALL, "");
                        //Toast.makeText(ctx, Call, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (Call.equals("online")) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, CallEndActivity.class);
                            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            ctx.startActivity(i);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}


/**
 * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
 */
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public OutgoingReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String outgng = Var.share.getString(Var.OUTGOING, "");
        checkedcall = Var.share.getString(Var.CHECKEDCALL, "");
        userChecked = Var.share.getString(Var.USERCHECKED, "");
        //context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), CallDetectService.class));
        Log.e("outgng", outgng);
        if (outgng.equals("outgng") && checkedcall.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("**********Inside BroadcaseReceiver class for detecting outgoing calls*********");
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            //context.startService(new Intent(context, CallDetectService.class));
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            Log.e("outgng1", checkedcall);
            Var.share = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Var.PERF, MODE_PRIVATE);
            Var.editor = Var.share.edit();
            Var.editor.putString(Var.CHECKEDCALL, "yes");
            Var.editor.putString(Var.OUTGOING, "0");
            Var.editor.commit();
            number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            setResultData(null);
            endCall(ctx);
            String tempData = date + "::" + "Outgoing::" + number + "\n";
            // Toast.makeText(context, tempData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent outcoming = new Intent(ctx, OutGoingCallActivity.class);
            outcoming.putExtra("mobilenumber", number);
            outcoming.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            ctx.startActivity(outcoming);
        }
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Var.share = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Var.PERF, MODE_PRIVATE);
                Var.editor = Var.share.edit();
                Var.editor.putString(Var.CHECKEDCALL, "no");
                Var.editor.putString(Var.OUTGOING, "outgng");
                Var.editor.putString(Var.USERCHECKED, "no");
                Var.editor.commit();
            }
        }, 5000);

        // logHelper.logTheRecord("callsLog.log", tempData);
    }


}

private Context ctx;
private TelephonyManager tm;
private CallStateListener callStateListener;

private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;

    callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
}

/**
 * Start calls detection.
 */
public void start() {
    System.out.println("**********Inside START DETECTING method*********");

    tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
}

/**
 * Stop calls detection.
 */
public void stop() {
    System.out.println("**********Inside STOP DETECTING method*********");

    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
}

public void endCall(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm);

        c = Class.forName(telephonyService.getClass().getName());
        m = c.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(telephonyService);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using alarmmanager, Service is not being restarted after application being killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798439/using-alarmmanager-service-is-not-being-restarted-after-application-being-kille)

Answer (score 0):

You could do by do some changes to your CallDetectService class :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
callHelper = new CallHelper(this);

    int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    callHelper.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
   callHelper.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("IWillStartAuto"));
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    callHelper.start();
}
```

Comment: in which class @Angus Tay

Comment: my bad, in CallDetectService

Comment: tried this. Service is not getting restarted automatically.

Comment: @kirubhasankar I have updated the code, still not working?

Comment: not working dude. When I remove the app from the task manager. it's not happens

Comment: In this case you have to reconstruct your code alongside with learning this post : https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Answer (score -1):

[google docs about process](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

its clear that google docs specifies that once the process has been killed ,the components int that process will all be destroyed.Maybe you would like to try multi-process to make your service run in another process.

Comment: He wants the service to keep on running just like you can still receive whatsapp message even you have kill the app.

Comment: exactly bro @Angus Tay